# Attempting to calculate the mobility from SCLC measurement (space charge limited current)

Tags: semiconductor-physics, measurements, solar-cells

I performed an SCLC measurement on a p-type material (hole transport layer) for a solar cell. Referring to the wikipedia page:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_charge

The relationship between $J$ and $V$ should be $J= \frac{9\epsilon\mu V^2}{8L^3}$ (Mott Gurney law), so $J$ should be proportional to $V^2$. From plotting $J$ vs $V$ it should therefore be possible to obtain the hole mobility.

However, in all of my results I found that this quadratic dependence is not true.

[image: J-V curve, NOT quadratic]

Plotting a log-log plot tells me that $J \propto V^{1.17}$

A student in the research group claim that this is a result of the layer being produced for this measurement being too thin, just 100$nm$ but I'm not so sure why this should give a completely different J-V characteristic.

So my first question is, do you have any idea why this is not a quadratic dependence, and could the small thickness of the layer explain this?

Secondly, on wikipedia I found another equation explaining the "Low Voltage Regime". It explains that for low voltages, $J = \frac{4\pi^2 k_b T \mu \epsilon V}{qL^3}$. I could fit a line to the very beginning of my curve (low voltage) and perhaps calculate the mobility this way. What I'm not sure about is how *low* is low? Are my increments small enough to get a meaningful measurement?

Thank you for any help.